# Appendix in Elsevier (elsarticle.cls) Journal

Tags: appendices, elsarticle, journal

I use (`elsarticle.cls`) for writing a journal paper for Elsevier Computer Networks Journal. I have an appendix section, I searched in manual for `elsarticle.cls` here:

https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf

But there is no indication how an Appendix Section should be displayed or are there any special commands for it.

For instance, with IEEE conference papers we have the command `\appendices` but could not find anything for Elsevier.

so I would like to know:

1. are there any special commands for the appendix section?
2. how should they be displayed? (e.g., by Appendix A, Appendix B, etc...), I would appreciate any document for that.
3. should Appendices be placed before or after References Section?

Comment: Not every documentclass knows `\appendices`. You could use the `appendix` package to get `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` -- The question where an appendix should be placed will provoke opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 25):

Use `\appendix` to determine when the section should be transform in appendix in `elsarticle` class.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

\appendix
\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just for the equations in Appendix A, should they have the normal numbering or should they have the prefix A, for instance, Eq. A.1? if yes, how should I achieve it? Another question is where should I put the Appendices before or after References Section?

Comment: @BenBost for equation let the class do the work for you (it is made by elsevier for a reason ;-) ). For the bibliography I'll put it between the main section and the appendix but perhaps the journal want something else. You have to ask them ;-)